# get diary from matlab command prompt

Tags: matlab

I would like to get the size of file which content is printed in the MATLAB command prompt ,
so to get the file , I did :

```
diary_file = tempname();
diary(diary_file);         
myFun(); 
diary('off');             
console_output = fileread(diary_file);
sizeOfFile = numel(console_output) % this doesn't give the size :(
```

This is not ok, as I want the size of file (3K as results for example , it's to check the file is not empty)

How could I get the size of file ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Matlab's function [`dir`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/dir.html):

```
aux = dir(diary_file);
sizeOfFile = aux.bytes;
```